# When is the first case where $67$ is the least prime factor of f(n)?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

Let *f(n)*=$1234567891011$....*n*

(concatenation of first n natural numbers). I make a sequence of numbers made with this following definition: *Smallest number n such that the m-th prime number is the least prime factor/divisor of f(n)*. And I found these following:

- *n*=2 is the first case where 2 is the least prime factor of *f(n)*
- *n*=3 is the first case where 3 is the least prime factor of *f(n)*
- *n*=25 is the first case where 5 is the least prime factor of *f(n)*
- *n*=43 is the first case where 7 is the least prime factor of *f(n)*
- *n*=157 is the first case where 11 is the least prime factor of *f(n)*
- *n*=19 is the first case where 13 is the least prime factor of *f(n)*
- *n*=271 is the first case where 17 is the least prime factor of *f(n)*
- And so on...
- And quite far:  *n*=793 is the first case where $83$ is the least prime factor of *f(n)*

My question: When is the first case where 67 is the least prime factor of *f(n)*? (Can 67 ever be the least prime factor of *f(n)*?). Additional question: Is there a prime number that will NEVER be the least prime divisor of *f(n)* ?

Comment: [Here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fOCFB.png) are all solutions below $10^4.$

Comment: @Lucian, you mean all of them have least prime factor of 67 ? (thanks for that information!) : D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is 2701. Checking in some more details.

Comment: you mean n=2701 is the first case where 67 is the least prime factor of f(n)?

Comment: Yes, that's what you were looking for, right? I wrote a program in Java and it says 2701 is the number.

Comment: What about least prime factor 89 and 97 ? ( I found n=523 for least prime factor 101) : D

Comment: It's 1531 for 89.

Comment: It's 1237 for 97.

Comment: Peter, would you like to continue ? :)

Comment: No, not really :)

Comment: I used pn# to check its least prime factor.Thanks Peter !

Comment: What is pn#? I am asking just out of curiosity. So... are my answers correct?

Comment: Primorial numbers (product of first n primes).

Comment: I am not sure what you're doing exactly. But whatever it is, it may turn into some interesting Project Euler problem :) I guess... Anyway, good luck.

Comment: I also got 89=>1531, 97=>1237, 101=>523, 103=>1867.  It gets more fun at e.g. 283=>11941, 409=>16729, 373=>25651, 389=>30901, 467=>47239.  For primes under 1000, 619 and 947 both have n > 50k.