# Can the prime $619$ ever be the least prime factor 0f f(n)?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

Let *f(n)*=$1234567891011$...*n* (i.e. concatenating the first n integers). And consider this sequence of numbers *n*:

- *n*=2 is the first case where 2 is the least prime factor of *f(n)*
- *n*=3 is the first case where 3 is the least prime factor of *f(n)*
- *n*=25 is the first case where 5 is the least prime factor of *f(n)*
- *n*=43 is the first case where 7 is the least prime factor of *f(n)*
- *n*=157 is the first case where 11 is the least prime factor of *f(n)*
- *n*=19 is the first case where 13 is the least prime factor of *f(n)*
- *n*=271 is the first case where 17 is the least prime factor of *f(n)*
- And so on....

So we have this sequence : $2,3,25,43,157,19,271,229,49,31,181,91,397,481,301,127,511,439,2701,37,79,253,793,1531,1237,523,1867,637$. My question : What is the smallest value of *n* such that $619$ is the least prime factor of *f(n)*?

-

Comment: Welcome to our site!

Comment: Sites like [this one](http://www.primepuzzles.net/puzzles/puzz_078.htm) might help.

Answer (score 1):

I used a simple Perl script with Math::GMPz, same as for [Kenan's almost identical question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1567816/when-is-the-first-case-where-67-is-the-least-prime-factor-of-fn?rq=1) a few days ago.  I noted there that 619 and 947 both had entries > 50k.

n=64033 for prime 619.

n=145591 for prime 947.

n=176053 for prime 1613, which is the largest n for primes under 2000.